# Should switch cover plates be installed before final inspection?

Tags: electrical, nec, inspection

For final inspection should I put the switch/outlet cover plates on? It's a minor pain because we still have to tape, sand and paint. We are in Portland Oregon. This is in a bedroom, not a kitchen or bathroom.

Comment: In my area the final inspection includes confirmation that all covers are installed properly, as it takes place after the preliminary electrical inspection which was for ensuring all devices and wiring methods were acceptable. Contact your inspector/ Authority Having Jurisdiction and they will be happy to let you know what they expect to see.

Comment: Catherine, I see that you have several questions outstanding where you haven't accepted answers but made affirmative comments on them. Please click the icon to accept answers that resolve your issue, and upvote those that are otherwise helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Usually they do require the cover plate to verify the box is set correctly.  Each inspector is different but some don't like DIY folks, especially in Lane County, Oregon. Benton & Linn counties were not so bad (I haven't worked up in Portland for ~15 years) but they usually want everything finished. I have seen inspectors fail an install because the wires were coated with sheet rock mud & paint.

Comment: thx. we will put the covers on!